# Failed to scan [file:/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/] from classloader hierarchy with embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I am facing issue starting the application with embedded tomcat, I'm using the latest version of eclipse (2021-12) and i've tried "mvn clean install" after deleting the repositories.

I even tried -   server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar
in application.properties. but it is not working. Please help.

```html
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.celebrus.dashboard.config.DashboardAppConfig$1.getTomcatWebServer(DashboardAppConfig.java:478) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.celebrus.dashboard.config.DashboardAppConfig$1.getWebServer(DashboardAppConfig.java:416) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.celebrus.dashboard.OperationsDashboardWebApplication.main(OperationsDashboardWebApplication.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor48.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\arunkumar.ravichandr\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.2\xml-apis.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1259) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:350) ~[na:na]
    ... 58 common frames omitted

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/E:/CelebrusDashboard9.5/tmp/ops-dashboard-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/arunkumar.ravichandr/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.6/logback-classic-1.2.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/arunkumar.ravichandr/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/arunkumar.ravichandr/.m2/repository/com/celebrus/automated-install/9.6/automated-install-9.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2022-01-27 19:05:33.952  INFO 16748 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2022-01-27 19:05:34.233  WARN 16748 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/arunkumar.ravichandr/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xercesImpl.jar] from classloader hierarchy

java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    

2022-01-27 19:05:34.235  WARN 16748 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/arunkumar.ravichandr/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xml-apis.jar] from classloader hierarchy

java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.celebrus.dashboard.config.DashboardAppConfig$1.getTomcatWebServer(DashboardAppConfig.java:478) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.celebrus.dashboard.config.DashboardAppConfig$1.getWebServer(DashboardAppConfig.java:416) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.celebrus.dashboard.OperationsDashboardWebApplication.main(OperationsDashboardWebApplication.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor48.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\arunkumar.ravichandr\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xml-apis.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1259) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:350) ~[na:na]
    ... 56 common frames omitted

2022-01-27 19:05:34.236  WARN 16748 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/arunkumar.ravichandr/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/serializer.jar] from classloader hierarchy

  

2022-01-27 19:05:34.823 ERROR 16748 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2022-01-27 19:05:34.873 ERROR 16748 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2022-01-27 19:05:34.875  INFO 16748 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/C:/Users/arunkumar.ravichandr/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.54/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when I migrated an older application to Spring boot (with Java 11). It was looking for the Xalan Serializer jar in the wrong package.

I resolved the issues by removing ESAPI from the dependencies and thus the versions of xalan & serializer dependencies that ESAPI has.